# How to get Browser details of client in ASP.NET core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, browser

I am working with sagepay Payment gateway.

For that, I want to get the following details of card holder.

Browser Accept Header

Browser Color Depth

Browser IP

Browser JavaEnabled

Browser Javascript Enabled

Browser Language

Browser Screen Height

Browser TZ - Time-zone offset in minutes between UTC and the Cardholder browser local time

Browser Screen Width

Browser UserAgent

clinet WindowSize

How can I get above details of the card holder?
Is there any package for this?

Comment: You might just search NPM for "browser fingerprint".  I found one here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-browser-fingerprint  You can view the source here: https://github.com/damianobarbati/get-browser-fingerprint/blob/main/src/index.js

Comment: Some of this info can be read server side cause it is usually send by browser or is part of the request, but in general you will need to have some client side library/code which will add this info to the request.